# Find minimum values of df column based on another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe

```
   index  X Coordinate  Y Coordinate  Z Coordinate  indices  distances
0      0    650355.148   4766450.315        39.086      537   0.348036
1      1    650355.148   4766450.314        39.086      537   0.347131
2      2    650372.398   4766676.602       -18.388      461   0.398005
3      3    650372.979   4766676.880       -18.087      461   0.591304
4      4    650373.776   4766677.397       -18.172      461   1.432126
```

and I want to find out minimum distances of each indices so I left with below

[image]

I tried df['distances'].min() could not quite get the result I want

Comment: Please, can you replace your image by plain text data? ty.

Comment: @Corralien yes replaced it sorry for trouble

Comment: Can you try my solution please? I think your output is wrong because 0.348036 > 0.347131 for indice 537.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby`:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby('indices')['distances'].idxmin()]

   index  X Coordinate  Y Coordinate  Z Coordinate  indices  distances
2      2    650372.398   4766676.602       -18.388      461   0.398005
1      1    650355.148   4766450.314        39.086      537   0.347131
```